# How to implement multiple authentication using Azure AD in .NET core 6 API (back end)?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, asp.net-core-6.0, azure-authentication

I'm trying to implement a dual authentication system for an application which uses Angular as front end and .NET core 6 API as back end. Authentication should be implemented for internal and external users. Internal users should be allowed to login using Azure AD authentication.  External users will be registered by the tool admin and will login by validating username and password they have entered from front end UI.

The implementation I'm trying is as follows:

Starts from Login page (which will not have AUTH guard):

1. **Internal Authentication:**
   **1.1** Frontend to request Internal Authentication API to authenticate
   **1.2** Internal Authentication API (Anonymous): Request Azure AD (using client credentials flow) to authenticate with a call back in place. If authenticated, request Token generation API to generate token
   **1.3** Token Generation API (Anonymous): Generate JWT token, which includes user role and email
   **1.4** Return the token back to frontend application
2. **External Authentication:**
   **2.1** Frontend to request External Authentication API to authenticate
   **2.2** External Authentication API (Anonymous): Query SQL DB and check if the user name and password is valid. If authenticated, request Token generation API to generate token
   **2.3** Token Generation API (Anonymous): Generate JWT token, which includes user role and email
   **2.4** Return the token back to frontend application

The external user authentication and token generation is in place with only the Internal authentication pending. I'm looking for help with section 1.2. I found a few relevant articles but none of them catered to what I was looking for exactly. I've listed them below -

- [SIGN-IN USING MULTIPLE CLIENTS OR TENANTS IN ASP.NET CORE AND AZURE AD](https://damienbod.com/2021/06/28/sign-in-using-multiple-clients-or-tenants-in-asp-net-core-and-azure-ad/)
- [How to Use Multiple Authentication Schemes in .NET](https://code-maze.com/dotnet-multiple-authentication-schemes/)
- [ASP.NET Core: Supporting multiple Authorization](https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-supporting-multiple-authorization-6502eb79f934)
- https://www.shedloadofcode.com/blog/multiple-authentication-schemes-with-aspnet-core-and-azure-active-directory

Any suggestions or available working samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To do the client credential ,for front-end, you need to make a request to get the token follow this description. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret
[image]

For back-end is a very easy sample you can use from visual studio that use Azure client credential on webapi. Create webapi choose the Microsoft identity platform.
[image]
In the appsettings, just modify the value of "Domain", "TenantId" and "ClientId". Then the "weatherforecast" api can only acess by request with the right bear token.
[image]

To find your TenantId and Domain
[image]

In the AAD-App registeration, create a new app(client) you will get the clientId and secret.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was looking for some help with azure ad authentication in the backend rather than in angular. I intend to make an anonymous call from Angular to the API to authenticate the user in the backend so that I can generate a JWT token if the user is authenticated (since I have to generate a token for an external user as well) and pass that token to angular so it can be used to make any other API calls.